# Finding subsets of ClearCase branch types

Tags: branch, clearcase

I'm working on a large project, for which several thousand branch types are defined, and would like to **quickly** retrieve a list of "my" branch types. This can be achieved either by listing branch types created by me, or by listing branch types whose names start with my username.

As the full list is huge and lstype runs for approximately an hour normally, is there a way to formulate a query that can be answered quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a native command able to return *quickly* an answer.
When looking at the [`cleartool lstype` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm), the technote "[LSTYPE performance improvements](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21206644)" does mention that:

> The `-short`, `-nostatus` and `-unsorted` options can be used to improve performance of the `cleartool lstype` command

But as with everything with ClearCase, this doesn't stand the test of the real world, where the number of (here) types quite be *really* big...

So what I usually do for this kind of request, considering I don't create a `brtype` every 5 minutes, is to have a batch job running every 2 hours, updating a list of `brtype` with the informations I need (owner, date, ...).

I can then at any time filter that file (at least the most updated version of that file) in order to extract the list of `brtype` I need.
There is the risk this list isn't up-to-date, but in practice this works relatively well.